# How to view TODO items in SQL Server Data Tools?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

Is it possible to have TODO items in an SSDT database project so that these items show up in the task viewer? Currently, I write `-- TODO Task...` in my files and they don't appear in the viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the "TODO" functionality isn't part of SSDT at this time. I'd love to have it for various BI/SQL projects, but never saw it working.

Comment: use the task list https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txtwdysk.aspx only works for C# code, do we have anything for DB project?